# Coffeescript in Rails 3.1 app executing on page load every time

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm having trouble with my coffeescript,  I'm trying to refresh a load of values once a ajax call is complete (using 'best_in_place'), and to do that in the tidiest way I've put all my code in a function that gets called as part of the callback.

However, it appears that rails wants to call this function on page load, rather than as a call back every time, why is this?

```
    jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place().bind("ajax:success", Statement.update_transactions())

Statement =  
  update_transactions : () ->
    alert('running update');
    $('.category_field').each( ->
      transaction_id = $(this).attr('data-transaction-id')
      $(this).find('.loading-transaction').show();
      $(this).find('.category-detail').hide();
      $(this).load('/transaction/update_category/'+transaction_id, ->
        $(this).find('.loading-transaction').hide();
      );
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis from Statement.update_transactions()

They cause the method to be invoked immediately. So just use:

```
$('.best_in_place').best_in_place().bind("ajax:success", Statement.update_transactions)
```